# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'uID' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, xampp

just started with Laravel. I have attached my user and profile models along with the profile controller. My goal is to assign the foreign key uID in the **profile** table automatically. Any help will be appreciated.

**user model file**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user extends Model
{
    // specify which attributes can be filled out during registration
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable=['firstname','lastname','email','password',];

    public function profile(){
      return $this->hasOne(profile::class,'pID','uID');
    }
}
```

**profile model file**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class profile extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['summary','uID'];

    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo(user::class,'uID','pID');
    }
}
```

**profile migration file**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
      // create profile table
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('pID');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->string('summary')->default('');
            $table->integer('uID')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('uID')->references('uID')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

**profile controller file**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\profile;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       // used to store user profile after validation
        $this->validate($request,[
          'summary' => 'required'
        ]);
        $profile = new profile([
          'summary' => $request->get('summary'),
        ]);
        $profile->save();

        return redirect()->route('profile.create')->with('success','Profile created');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving `uID` a default value?

Comment: I used nullable() as default and the problem goes away, but then it makes uID null. I was hoping to set uID to User('uID') as I keep adding users and the associated profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your migration file,
As you wanted to define your relationship later, So your foreign id field should be nullable.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
// create profile table
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('pID');
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->string('summary')->default('');
$table->integer('uID')->nullable()->unsigned();

$table->foreign('uID')
        ->references('uID')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
}
}
```

And If you wanted to assign Logged in user after create profile,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\profile;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       // used to store user profile after validation
        $this->validate($request,[
          'summary' => 'required'
        ]);
        $profile = new profile([
          'summary' => $request->get('summary'),
          'uID'     => auth()->user()->id,

        ]);
        $profile->save();

        return redirect()->route('profile.create')->with('success','Profile created');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't providing value in your program, you need to provide default value on table definition level.

According to your description it seems you are missing to create a profile after creating a user record.

Comment: I have used nullable() as default value and the problem goes away but how do I set uID to User('uID'). uID is a foreign key referencing the User('uID'). I want to keep adding new users and their associated profiles without manually setting the uID foreign key in profile table.

Comment: So you will add user with ID as autoincrement and you don't have last autoincrement sequence value for it at time you need create a new profile. Am I right? Try to provide selecting user object back to get an autoincrement value.

Comment: Yes. How do I implement your suggestion? Do I add $profile['uID'] = $profile->user()->uID before $profile->save()

Comment: @AmartyaBarua: Thats not correct. in $profile->user() there will be null at that time probably. At worst case you need call to on database something like SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = '...' AND lastname = '...' AND email = '...' to get your autoincrement back to your program. I don't know mechanics of working of Laravel. Many frameworks also updates the entity automatically for database data after its send to database.